# Different results with MsBuild and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution, which consists out of 2 projects: regular class library for .NET 4.5 + website (not **web application**) project.

When I build this solution with Visual Studio - all referenced assemblies from Nuget packages and local references are copied to bin folder of website project.

If I try to build solution with MsBuild - bin folder of website project does not receive any assemblies.

Website project is not selected to be built in VS configuration (which is reported by message in both cases)

**Edit** - here is additional explanation.

When I clone a project from git - bin folder of website contains only 4 assemblies already checked in:
[image: Initial bin after clone]

If I will run msbuild command with /t:Build or /t:Rebuild and /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU" - I'll receive just an output of postbuild event in my other project, included in solution:
[image: After MsBuild]

However, if I execute build from VS (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>) in Release/Debug config - bin have all required assemblies for running web application.
[image: After build in VS]

**Edit 2**: Link to example solution - https://github.com/akuryan/csharp-website-test

When one builds it with  `msbuild TestApp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"` - this results in only Test.Core.* and LetsEncrypt.Umbraco.dll (initially checked in) found at `~\Test.Web\bin\` (where Test.Web is website project). If one builds TestApp.sln with VisualStudion 2015 (I suppose, 2013 and 2017 will be the same) - `~\Test.Web\bin\` gets whole amount of assemblies.

Comment: would you mind sharing us the github link so that we could reproduce this issue?

Comment: See latest edit2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Different results with MsBuild and Visual Studio

That because the all `dll.refresh` file in bin folder alongside the binary file are ignored by `.gitignore`.

Since Web Site projects do not have any project file (.csproj) to put the assembly references, the `*.dll.refresh` files are used by MSBuild to understand the assembly references. The contents of the file is the relative path to the `.dll` via the packages folder for the solution. When you ignore all those `.dll`.refresh by `.gitignore`, MSBuild could not understand how to handle the `dll` files.

To test this, I created a website project, add a nuget package to it, then delete the `dll` files but keep the `.dll.refresh` files in the `bin` folder. Build the website project by MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild.exe TestWebsite.sln /t:Rebuild
```

After this command complete, the `dll` files are copy to the `bin` folder.

So build and package restore to work it looks like you need to **keep the `.dll.refresh` files in the bin folder**. You can remove the other binaries from your version control system.

Note: If you want to get those `.dll.refresh` back, you can use the command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

Hope this helps.